# PHP does not upload file on localhost

Tags: php, upload, xampp, localhost

I am reading "Head first PHP book" and stumbled at chapter 5 where file upload is implmented. I did it on XAMPP on windows 7. The path to the file is the following:

```
htdocs-->chapter5-->form.php
```

Here is my simplified version of the original code.

```
<html>
   <head>
       <title>Guitar Wars - Add Your High Score</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
   <head>
   <body>
      <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
            // Grab the score data from the POST
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $score = $_POST['score'];
            $screenshot=$_FILES['screenshot']['name'];
            if (!empty($name) && !empty($score) && !empty($screenshot)) 
            {
              // Connect to the database
              $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("could not connect to the database");
              mysqli_select_db($dbc, "store") or die("could not choose the database");
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image/.$screenshot') or die("problem uploading");
            // Write the data to the database
              $query = "INSERT INTO scores VALUES (0, NOW(), '$name', '$score', '$screenshot')";
              mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or mysqli_errno();//die ("could not create record");
              // Confirm success with the user
              echo '<p>Thanks for adding your new high score!</p>';
              echo '<p><strong>Name:</strong> ' . $name . '<br />';
              echo '<strong>Score:</strong> ' . $score . '</p>';
              echo '<p><a href="index.php">&lt;&lt; Back to high scores</a></p>';
              // Clear the score data to clear the form
              $name = "";
              $score = "";
              mysqli_close($dbc);
           }
         else 
        {
                echo '<p class="error">Please enter all of the information to add your high score.</p>';
        }
    }
?>
 <hr />

    <h2>Guitar Wars - Add Your High Score</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
           <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="32768">   
           <label for="name">Name:</label>
           <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php if (!empty($name)) echo $name; ?>" /><br />
           <label for="score">Score:</label>
           <input type="text" id="score" name="score" value="<?php if (!empty($score)) echo $score; ?>" />
 <br />
           <label for="screenshot">Screenshot:</label> <input type="file" id="screenshot" name="screenshot"> <hr/>          
           <input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit" />
   </form>
</body>
```

The whole idea is the following. User  enters his name and score and selects file for upload via self-submitting html form:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
           <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="32768">   
           <label for="name">Name:</label>
           <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="<?php if (!empty($name)) echo $name; ?>" /><br />
           <label for="score">Score:</label>
           <input type="text" id="score" name="score" value="<?php if (!empty($score)) echo $score; ?>" />
 <br />
           <label for="screenshot">Screenshot:</label> <input type="file" id="screenshot" name="screenshot"> <hr/>          
           <input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit" />
   </form>
```

then the data is processed by php script in the same file:

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        // Grab the score data from the POST
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $score = $_POST['score'];
        $screenshot=$_FILES['screenshot']['name'];
        if (!empty($name) && !empty($score) && !empty($screenshot)) 
        {
          // Connect to the database
          $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("could not connect to the database");
          mysqli_select_db($dbc, "store") or die("could not choose the database");
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image/.$screenshot') or die("problem uploading");
        // Write the data to the database
          $query = "INSERT INTO scores VALUES (0, NOW(), '$name', '$score', '$screenshot')";
          mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or mysqli_errno();//die ("could not create record");
          // Confirm success with the user
          echo '<p>Thanks for adding your new high score!</p>';
          echo '<p><strong>Name:</strong> ' . $name . '<br />';
          echo '<strong>Score:</strong> ' . $score . '</p>';
          echo '<p><a href="index.php">&lt;&lt; Back to high scores</a></p>';
          // Clear the score data to clear the form
          $name = "";
          $score = "";
          mysqli_close($dbc);
       }
     else 
    {
            echo '<p class="error">Please enter all of the information to add your high score.</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

When i try to submit the form for processig  the message is

```
   problem uploading
```

which suggests that move_uploaded file failed. What i did are the following:

1. Chagged permission of the entire htdocs folder - did not work.
2. Created image folder within the chapter5 directory and changed its permission it did not work. I.e. created directory image as

   ```
     htdocs-->chapter5-->image
   ```

   and changed permissions of the directory. then I called move_uploaded_file as

   ```
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'], 
    '/image/.$screenshot') or die("problem uploading");
   ```

   this approach did not work
3. Created image directory in the htdocs directory and tried the following call

   ```
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image/.$screenshot') or die("problem uploading");
   ```

every time i have

```
    probem uploading
```

text written on the page after form submission. I looked at file_upload record in the php.ini file everyhting seem fine:

```
    ; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
    ; specified).
    ; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
      upload_tmp_dir="C:\xampp1\tmp"

    ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
    ; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
      upload_max_filesize=40M

    ; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
    max_file_uploads=2
```

I also changed the permmision of 'C:\xampp1\tmp'

Nothing worked. Can anybody suggest what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give us the final file name `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/image/.$screenshot`, echo it and exit

Comment: `'/image/.$screenshot'` likely should be `'/image/'.$screenshot`

Comment: are u asking me the full path name?

Comment: @waterloomatt, yes, this is just typo

Answer (score 1):

First things first, turn on error reporting so you can see the actual error/warning that is happening - [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

I ran your code and it works *if the destination directory actually exists*. One approach to ensuring that it exists is to create the directory on the fly.

Not sure if this is the right location for you, but using `./image/` will create the *image* in the directory where your script is executing. You can play around with `$destinationDirectory` until you get your desired location and it should continue to work.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

...
if (!empty($name) && !empty($score) && !empty($screenshot)) {

    $destinationDirectory = './image/';

    // Check if the destination is a directory. If not, create it. 
    if (!is_dir($destinationDirectory) && !mkdir($destinationDirectory)) {
        die("Error creating folder $destinationDirectory");
    }

    $finalPath = $destinationDirectory . $screenshot;

    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'], $finalPath)) {
        die("problem uploading");
    }

    ...
```

> `'/image/.$screenshot'` likely should be `'/image/'.$screenshot`
>
> @waterloomatt, yes, this is just typo

You should edit your question with the real code then otherwise, it will throw people off.

And final note - `$query = "INSERT INTO scores VALUES (0, NOW(), '$name', '$score', '$screenshot')";`
This code is fully susceptiable to SQL injection because you're passing user supplied data directly to your database. Look into *prepared statements* - https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared

Comment: If you DV, please leave a reason why.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty obvious. I created simple form.html file and separate form.php form handler. When 2 are separate then everything works fine. When the form is self-submitting it gave me error messages. Looks like this is related to form submission.

Comment: Glad you fixed it but that doesn't make much sense. Something else is happening here.